# My mouse extra buttons' behavior just changed... help?

Tags: mouse

Ubuntu 14.04 user.

Until today, my mouse extra buttons (6 & 7 I believe) had the "Navigate backward" and "Navigate forward" functionality. Today, they do copy-paste.
I updated Ubuntu yesterday, so it might have something to do with it.

I searched around to find how to remap those buttons. `btnx` seems to be dead, `easystroke` doesn't register these buttons and I couldn't find any mouse specific option in `CompizConfig`.

How would I go about mapping system functions to my extra mouse buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Setting Forward And Back Buttons
If all you want to do is set your four or five button mouse to use the extra buttons as "forward" and "back" buttons, you may have success with performing only a single action: edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf in the mouse section, and add the following two lines:

Option "Buttons" "7"
Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 6 7"
Make sure to backup the file first, and restart X to have the effect take place. Assuming you are one of the fortunate people who only wants these functions and whose mouse buttons map as the "standard" behavior, you'll be all set.

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations#Setting_Forward_And_Back_Buttons